# South scheme migration apparently didn't work

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-south

Okay, so I had an app called locationmanager with a model that looks like this:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region)
```

and I want to change it to this

```
class Location(models.Model):
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, blank=True, null=True)
```

After changing it, I ran a schemamigration that looked like the following:

```
    $ python manage.py schemamigration locationmanager --auto
     ? The field 'Location.region' does not have a default specified, yet is NOT NULL.
     ? Since you are making this field nullable, you MUST specify a default
     ? value to use for existing rows. Would you like to:
     ?  1. Quit now.
     ?  2. Specify a one-off value to use for existing columns now
     ?  3. Disable the backwards migration by raising an exception; you can edit the migration to fix it later
     ? Please select a choice: 2
     ? Please enter Python code for your one-off default value.
     ? The datetime module is available, so you can do e.g. datetime.date.today()
     >>> 0
     ~ Changed field region on locationmanager.Location
     ? The field 'Location.manager' does not have a default specified, yet is NOT NULL.
     ? Since you are making this field nullable, you MUST specify a default
     ? value to use for existing rows. Would you like to:
     ?  1. Quit now.
     ?  2. Specify a one-off value to use for existing columns now
     ?  3. Disable the backwards migration by raising an exception; you can edit the migration to fix it later
     ? Please select a choice: 0
     ! Invalid choice.
     ? Please select a choice: 2
     ? Please enter Python code for your one-off default value.
     ? The datetime module is available, so you can do e.g. datetime.date.today()
     >>> 0
     ~ Changed field manager on locationmanager.Location
    Created 0003_auto__chg_field_location_region__chg_field_location_manager.py. You can now apply this migration with: ./manage.py migrate locationmanager

$ sudo python manage.py migrate locationmanager --fake
Running migrations for locationmanager:
 - Migrating forwards to 0003_auto__chg_field_location_region__chg_field_location_manager.
 > locationmanager:0002_initial
   (faked)
 > locationmanager:0003_auto__chg_field_location_region__chg_field_location_manager
   (faked)
```

After running the test, the form spit the error out at me:

```
   IntegrityError at /dash/location/add
    locationmanager_location.region_id may not be NULL
```

I had thought that I changed it? What could I have done wrong? What can I do currently to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You specify a `--fake` migration. Fake your initial migration to get to the current state (before the change) and them migrate regularly.

### Edit (based on the comments):

In order to fix the migration you will have to roll back to migration 0002 using

```
./manage.py migrate locationmanager 0002
```

Migration 0002 is faked, and it's fine, because you probably don't want south to change the db scheme for the state before the change.

Now you can migrate regularly to migration 0003 using

```
./manage.py migrate locationmanager
```

Note that you can always look at the list of applied migrations using

```
./manage.py migrate locationmanager --list
```

Comment: What? I used --fake on the migration as shown in the terminal. How/why would you --fake an initial migration?

Comment: @ApathyBear why are you faking the migration? Faking it will only mark the migration as done but will do nothing on a database level

Comment: Well, thats good to know. What should I have done instead @CésarBustíos

Comment: @ApathyBear I guess you can go back to previous migrations and migrate again without the --fake flag